# Modify an Oracle Dataguard destination database

Tags: oracle, replication, dataguard

I'd like to set up some Oracle triggers to take action after rows are inserted, but I can't do this on our production database because it's controlled by a vendor. One alternative I was looking at is doing Oracle Dataguard replication to a secondary database somewhere, and setting up triggers there to take my action. However, I've gotten the impression that I can't modify the Dataguard destination in any way, even if my triggers won't have impact on the data at all (they're all AFTER triggers).

Can I use dataguard in this way? If I can't, are there are other alternatives to Dataguard, like maybe Oracle streams? Some other type of replication?

Comment: I doubt the vendor will allow you to set up any kind of replication if they won't even let you add an after trigger

Comment: It's not one trigger - it's one on every table. We're using it as a step to replicate the data to an MSSQL Server, which requires their DDL trigger on every table. Even if it was supported, I don't want to potentially slow down the operations by introducing this kind of load on the production server if I can do it on a native Oracle replica of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

If you setup a logical standby, then you can change the data in the logical standby. You will probably have trouble supporting the kind of change that you seem to want. Have you thought about talking to the vendor to see if they can add the logic that you want to the product you pay them for? If the vendor makes the change, then they will/should support it. You can create materialized views in a different schema and add whatever functionality that you want to the materialized views. You then just need to refresh them when needed.

Comment: We're using it as a stepping stone to replicate into MSSQL Server, which requires that we put a trigger on every single table in the database. It's not something the vendor will support, and not functionality they're interested in adding at this time (I wish it was).

Comment: Try setting up a logical standby database that has triggers to send the data to SQL Server. You can use heterogenous connectivity to connect to SQL Server.